# Docker run gives error `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, sinatra

I have been trying to create a docker image and run the ruby files

Following is the code for creating the docker image

```
FROM ruby:3

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN gem install bundler && \
    bundle config --global frozen 1 && \
    bundle install

RUN gem install extensions
COPY app.rb config.ru database.rb utils.rb thin.rb ./

EXPOSE 8080

CMD exec thin -R config.ru -p 8080 start
```

I also tried `CMD bundle exec thin start` instead of last command above.

I then execute the following command to build the image

`sudo docker build -t project3 .`

And the **build is successful**.

But when I run `docker run -p 8080:8080 project3`

I receive the following error

```
mayuresh@mayuresh-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB:~/Softwares/CS291_project3$ sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 project3
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/regular.rb:22:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `block in new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/equality_map.rb:43:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann/pattern.rb:59:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:67:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `block in new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mustermann-1.0.3/lib/mustermann.rb:70:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1641:in `compile'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1629:in `compile!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1271:in `error'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1831:in `<class:Base>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:889:in `<module:Sinatra>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/main.rb:26:in `<module:Sinatra>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra/main.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sinatra-2.0.7/lib/sinatra.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `rescue in require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:149:in `require'
    from /app/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
<internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /app/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:203:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:159:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thin-1.7.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried implementing the code mentioned on
[Link1](https://www.codewithjason.com/dockerize-sinatra-application/)
[Link2](https://blog.cloud66.com/deploying-rest-apis-to-docker-using-ruby-and-sinatra/)

Also, I would like to mention that earlier I have dockerized many projects with similar docker file, but I don't understand what could be the problem associated in this approach.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release history for `mustermann`](https://github.com/sinatra/mustermann#release-history) says that support for ruby `v3.0.0` was added in `v1.1.0`.

You are using ruby `v3.0.0` with mustermann `v1.0.3`.

Either downgrade ruby to 2.7, or upgrade mustermann to 1.1.0+

Comment: Note: I'm **guessing** that you only encountered this error after upgrading ruby to v3? In which case, you might also encounter other similar issues with out of date dependencies... There are some backward-incompatible changes, you might face errors running old code with it!

Comment: Here's was the PR that added support: https://github.com/sinatra/mustermann/pull/97